# Can't implement generics with java.lang.annotation.Annotation: incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, annotations

I am wanting to generically retrieve annotations based on where a provided is retrieving values.  Either from a field or getters/setters.  So, a provider needs to return information in a `Field` annotation.  There are other annotations planned, so the implementations needs to be generic.

The method is exactly what is in the `java.lang.Class` class.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public interface Setter<Instance, Type>
{
    <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass);
}
```

But, when I use the method..

```
final Field annotation = setter.getAnnotation(Field.class);
```

I get a complication error..

```
incompatible types
found   : java.lang.annotation.Annotation
required: Field
```

This makes nearly no sense because `Field` is an `Annotation`!

Are there special considerations to give to annotations while implementing generics?

Why isn't this working??  It is exactly like the Java API.

Just for more information, here is the `Field` annotation.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Field
{
    /**
     * The effective path of the local or result set value to load into the field.
     */
    String value() default "";
}
```

Comment: Make sure that `setter` is not an instance of raw type (i.e. that it's declared as `Setter<...>`, not `Setter`).

Comment: That shouldn't matter because you can see that the generic is local to the method (similar to the Class in the Java API)

Comment: It's quite counterintuitive decision of the language designers, but it matters. When you use raw types, you disable all generic declarations within these types.

Comment: Interesting, which compiler/version are you using? It seems that ecj compiles it without any issues.

Comment: Counter intuitive is right @axtavt!  In this case, I don't actually need the `Setter` interface to be generic...  thanks! :)